# many grades for student array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to fix a small program for student grades .
I have a class for students . and in my main program I add student in to the ArrayList through the input. and later i want to add many grades for exat that student.

What should i do ? I would prefer to use the array . but I do not know how . Can i create a new array everytime i create a new student and add the grades?

```
private String name;
private float grade;


public void student(String name, float grade){
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;

}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}


public float getGrade(){
    return grade;
}







public String toString(){
    return String.format(name + " have grades " + grade );                          
}
```

Comment: Use `LinkedList` if the size of the collection is dynamic

Comment: So what are you asking for?

Comment: or hashmap, but you will need an Array inside the student class for the grades, you have a List of Student Objects, each Student Object should have Name, Array of Grades etc, etc. Data design is very important before starting to write a Program.

Comment: how can i add many grades for each student that i create? @Lopan

Comment: an array of grades for each student.

Comment: Should i have array like an atributte in class student? @DanielNetzer

Comment: search hashmap its what u need for this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just change grades from a float into an array of floats.

```
public class Student{
        private String name;
        private float[] grades;


        public void Student(String name, float[] grades){

            this.name = name;
            this.courses = Arrays.copyOf(grades, grades.length);

        }

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }


        public float getGradeAtIndex(int index){
            return grades[index];
        }

    // Add methods, getters, setters as you wish.
}
```

pay attention this code havent been tested so in the getGradeAtIndex method you might insert an index which is out of the array bounds there should be a check before it actually try to pull data and return null incase that check fails.

try and use the correct programming format it'll make easy on your life in future. class names should start with a Capital letter, methods and var's with camelCases.

hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: In this case he must know the number of grades before creating an student. He does not say if he knows or not so I would use dinamic ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unknown number of grades per student, use an `ArrayList` of grades.

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<float> grades;


public void student(String name){
    this.name = name;

}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}    

public void addGrade(float grade){
    this.grades.add(grade);
}

public String toString(){
    return String.format(name + " have grades " + grade );                          
}
```

Do not forget to import it from `java.util.ArrayList`. Check the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: yea the constructors and getters setters will be a bit more complexed to handle.

Comment: Yes but he can use all the functions that `ArrayList` already has. Handling more grades is more complex than just one grade by student, but also has more posibilities.